# Preventing Subview from Transforming when its Superview Transforms

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I have the following set up. I have a `UIView` called `parentView` that holds a `UIView` called `childView`. `parentView` can be rotated and resized using some touch gestures which need to be on the `parentView`. `childView` has some drawing code in its drawRect method which needs to updated as the `parentView` is transformed.

I am noticing when I transform the `parentView` (scale or rotate), `childView` automatically gets transformed as well. Problem with this is, while I do want the rotate transform to be initiated on the `childView`, I don't want it to be scale, I'd rather execute its drawing code.

So my question is, what is a good way to handle this situation? I notice when I call "`setNeedsDisplay`" on my `childView` after `parentView` is transformed, it doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to apply the rotation to the `parentView`, and then set the bounds property of `parentView` and `childView` to resize it. Then I was able to redraw the `childView` in `drawRect` successfully. Bottom line is though I think if you set a transform on a childs superview, I think you're stuck having to live with it in its subviews. I tried setting the transforms separately and all of the timing of the transforms got screwed up. The above situation from Brent might also come in handy for certain situations.

Answer (score 2):

Don't transform the parent view; transform a sibling of the child view.

In other words, your current set up looks like this:

```
transformedView
    childView
```

Instead, do this:

```
parentView
    transformedView
    childView
```

That way the transformation won't affect the child.

Comment: This is a good idea, but in my situation it involves rotation between the parentView and all the subviews, so after that's done, if I try to set a new transform for any of the subviews, it gets messed up.

Comment: But what If I want to achieve something like Marry-Go-round where cabins moves with rotation but remains vertically straight?