# Animated transform only for superview

Tags: swift, core-animation, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to animate the scale of the parent `outerView`, but keep child `innerView` with it's size, so that parent view transform just clips it during animation. For some reason, an inverted transform is scaling child view to bigger size.

Without inverted transform parent and child transforms equally.

```
    @IBAction func transformAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let animation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 5, curve: .linear) {
        self.outerView.transform = self.outerView.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 0.1)
        self.innerView.transform = self.outerView.transform.inverted()
    }

    animation.addCompletion { _ in
        self.outerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        self.innerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }

    animation.startAnimation()
}
```

[image: Layput of views]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you create a new transform for `innerView`, instead of inverting the `outerView` one? To understand what's going on: What is the `innerView`'s `transform` after the animation, if you only transform `outerView`? (I'd guess that this transform is applied to all `outerView`'s offspring.) Interesting!

Comment: It's clearer to see what's happening if the outer view doesn't clip the inner view. `innerView` immediately starts scaling up to 10x height, but as `outerView` scales down past 50% `innerView` starts shrinking again.

Comment: @AshleyMills yes exactly, `innerView` always shrinks even transform matrix is for scaling up.

Comment: @meaning-matters it doesn't matter how transform is created, animation stays the same. `innerView`s transform after the animation is equal to transform before animation if only `outerView` transform applied.

Comment: Why do you want this? Does `innerView` need to be a child of `outerView`, or could they be overlapping siblings?

Comment: @meaning-matters I need to create the animation where `outerView` is collapsing by height and clips all inside content, while all inner views just fading out during animation without any distortion.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15582691/1971013) is what you need to do.

Comment: @meaning-matters my goal is to clip `innerVIew` without its scale change, that way it would not clip it.

Answer (score 2):

Make `innerView` and `outerView` siblings in a `parentView`, where of course `innerView` is overlapping `outerView`.

Then animate the `transform` of `outerView` as you already do.

Finally, also animate the height of `parentView`. (Make sure that `parentView.clipsToBounds` is `true`.)

(The above assumes that `outerView` has content that needs to be compressed vertically. Of course, if there is no such content, you don't need a `parentView` and can just animate the height of `outerView`.)

BTW, the end result of your animation indeed has `innerView` back to its original height. But you don't see this in your animation because of `outerView` clipping. It's during the animation that the transforms mess up.

Comment: this approach doesn't work as expected for two reasons: 1) siblings can't clip each other view so `outerView` don't clip content of `innerView` 2) during height animation all child views maintain top space to the `parentView`, so as the result it looks like they are all sliding down. What I need is to shrink `outerView` while `innerView` stays the same position relative to the screen and keep its original scale.

Comment: @Jurasic Did you try to animate `height` auto-layout constraints together with constraints that keep both views at `parentView`'s center?

Comment: just did and it worked! `innerView` constraints keep view positioned and scaled appropriate

Comment: @Jurasic Great! Don't forget to accept and up the answer ;-)